# Python get logged in username when running as a windows service

Tags: python, winapi, windows-services

I complied my python script to an **exe** using **pyinstaller**. I ran it as a windows service using **nssm**. I need to get the logged in username. But it shows the username as **SYSTEM**. I used **os.getlogin().** I even tried **getpass** library. Still doesn't work. It works fine if it ran as an executable file. But I need to run it as a service.

Can anyone help me.

I need to get the logged in username when ran my python script as a service

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Since your program is running as a service, the username is `SYSTEM`, as you discovered. What value do you expect to be returned if there are multiple users logged in at the same time?